# SQL server 2017 distributed availability group connectivity after failover

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

I'm going to deploy SQL server distributed availability groups with SQL server 2017.

From the documentation, I understand that we can have listeners for primary AG and secondary AG.

The application now talking to primary AG listener. But after the failover, what will happen?

Will it use the primary AG listener name? How my applications know the new SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

> Although each underlying availability group of the distributed
> availability group has a listener, a distributed availability group
> has no listener.

[Distributed availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15)

So you must reconfigure the clients or alter the DNS entry for the hostname the clients are using to connect to the primary AG.

Answer (score 0):

The listener is a virtual network name for the instance (for the availability group to be more precise) with a defined ip and port. When a falover occurs it moves to the new primary node so that the applications can re-establish the connection without changing the connection string.